# How to get text of number elements and put into array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to to get text of number elements and put into array with jquery.but get this error that :

> Uncaught TypeError: aTags[i].parent is not a function.

How to solve this?

```
    $('#flight-stops-filter ul li a').click(function() {
    var aTags=$('#flight-stops-filter ul li a');
    stops = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
        if (aTags[i].parent("li").hasClass('active')) {
            alert(this.text);
            stops.push(this.text.substr(0, 1));
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: `aTags[i]` is DOM element wrap it with jquery wrapper..instead of `aTags[i].parent(..` use `$(aTags[i]).parent(..`

Comment: It looks like `DOM` not `jQ` wrapped element..use `$(aTags[i])`

Comment: Or you should play with `var aTags=$('#flight-stops-filter ul li');` and then in loop, `$(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the variable in a jQuery object (change `aTags[i].parent` to `$(aTags[i]).parent`):

```
if ($(aTags[i]).parent("li").hasClass('active')) {
   alert(this.text);
   stops.push(this.text.substr(0, 1));
}
```

or:

```
$('#flight-stops-filter ul li a').click(function() {
   var lis=$('#flight-stops-filter ul li.active');
   if (lis.length > 0 ) {
      alert(this.text);
   }
}
```

Comment: Makes zero sense to wrap it if you reference the element the right way to start

Answer (score 2):

When you use bracket notation

```
 aTags[i].parent("li")
```

it returns a DOM node

You want to use `eq(index)`

```
aTags.eq(i).parent("li")
```

Now inside the loop the use of `this.text` may be wrong too since there is no `text` property in DOM.

So what you probably want is

```
$('#flight-stops-filter ul li a').click(function() {
    var aTags=$('#flight-stops-filter ul li a');
    stops = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
        var li = aTags.eq(i).parent("li");
        if (li.hasClass('active')) {
            console.log(li.text());
            stops.push(li.text().substr(0, 1));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`aTags` is Jquery Object with pure DOM objects wrapped inside. So, you won't be able to invoke jquery methods on pure DOM objects without wrapping them inside jquery.

Replace your for loop with

```
   aTags.each(function(){
     if( $(this).parent("li").hasClass('active'))
     {
         alert(this.text);
         stops.push(this.text.substr(0, 1));
     }
   });
```

As suggested here in [jquery learning documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), rather than accessing via brackets notation you need to access it via `eq` method of jquery.

```
aTags.eq( 0 );//for first DOM object wrapped inside a jquery object
```

For accessing the DOM object

```
aTags.get(0) ;//same as aTags[0];
```

Comment: what happens if he has multiple selects?

Comment: @madalinivascu didn't get you... can you elaborate `multiple selects`?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error has been well explained by others. This alternative is both straight forward and there's no chance of you running into that error:

```
var links = $('#flight-stops-filter ul li a');
links.click(function() {
    stops = links.parent('.active').find('a').map(function() {
        return $(this).text().substr(0,1);
    }).get();
});
```